# Android Studio not showing code changes and unable to generate signed apk of recent changes

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, react-native

If I build my app using react-native run-android, I'm able to see my most recent changes on the android studio simulator. However, if I just open my project in Android Studio and run the app, the simulator runs an extremely old version of my app (from quite some time ago).
For development purposes, this has not been an issue as I just ran react-native run-android to see my changes. However, now that I'm trying to upload a signed release version of the app onto the playstore, I'm finding that the generated signed apk is of the old version.

Things I've tried:

- removing/adding Gradle Aware Make
- restarting Android Studio / my pc
- invalidating caches/restart
- turning off instant run
- cleaning/rebuilding project

Answer (score 1):

I'd say to try to follow the docs in this link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#docsNav

Since you successfully built it before then it's probably the same version of 1 that you had previously.

Try to change the gradle version in your app/build.gradle. 
Under default config:

```
defaultConfig { ... 
versionCode 1
versionName "1"
}
    signingConfigs {
```

Change the 1 to 2 and run the gradlew assembleRelease after clean.

Proof of Concept:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.risenradiance

Comment: Thanks for you input! However...the main issue I'm having is not necessarily getting a build up to the play store (I've successfully been able to do that) - however, the apk that's being uploaded is an old one. 
The main issue I'm having is that when I build the app from Android Studio (or generate a signed apk), I build/generate an old version.

Comment: Did you get to change the build.gradle  to versionCode 2
versionName "2"
} signingConfigs { ... this will generate the app-sign.apk again in a new updated version to launch in store.

Comment: Tried that - but it's still building an older version of the apk when I build on my machine locally through Android Studio.

Comment: Do you have two copies of the project? ; that happened to me and in the docs when producing the keystore, it can only have one... If you read into the link above it is in highlighted warning. Try npm installing in your directory, then running npm run start to try to get that directory to read your project. Then in android folder in the grade....if not  try to delete the apk. Run the gradlew clean then gradlew installRelease then gradlew assembleRelease --info to see what is getting implemented.

Comment: In the android/app/build.gradle there is def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false.... try to change enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture =  true and see if it builds the apks out if not its something else up in your environment if all else doesn't work.